# what is happening exactly when i use pointers the following way?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

```
int * func()
{
    static int array[10];
    int i = 0;
    while(i<10){
        array[i] = i + 1;
        i++;
    }
    return array;
}

int main()
{
    int *pointerFunc;
    pointerFunc = func();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      printf("*(pointerFunc[%d]) : %d\n", i, *(pointerFunc + i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have a function which creates an array. In main, I want to print every element from that array. I used a pointer to get "access" to my array in the function. It does work the way it is, but I don't really understand why. To be precise, I wonder what is happening here (sure it prints the studd, but the pointer thing...):
`printf("*(pointerFunc[%d]) : %d\n", i, *(pointerFunc + i));`
I don't quite understand this:
`*(pointerFunc + i)`
It works, but how and why? It does print every element of my array, but I dont't get it.
What is the pointer "seeing"?

Comment: For any array or pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`. Also, array naturally *decay* to pointers to their first element. So `return array;` is the same as `return &array[0];`. So the pointer variable `pointerFunc` "sees" the first element of the array in the `func` function, which you can then use as any other array or pointer.

Comment: What part of it do you have problem with? Would you know what `*pointerFunc` will print and why?

Comment: As Confucius said, the beginning of wisdom is to call things by their right name.  The right name is not `pointerFunc` because it is not a function. The right name is `intPointer` because it is a pointer. And it points to `int`.

Comment: Are you confused by the function or the notation?  Make sure you understand `int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}; int *int_pointer = a; for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){ printf("%d\n", *(int_pointer + i)); }`  The function doesn't add anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("*(pointerFunc[%d]) : %d\n", i, *(pointerFunc + i));
```

Here, you are using pointer arithmetic to access each element of the array.

The expression `*(pointerFunc + i)` adds `i` to the memory address stored in `pointerFunc`, and then dereferences the resulting memory address to access the value stored in that memory location. Since `pointerFunc` points to the first element of the array, `*(pointerFunc + i)` gives you the value stored in the `i`-th element of the array.

Alternatively, you could also use the array subscript operator `[]` to access the elements of the array using the pointer variable, like this:

```
printf("pointerFunc[%d] : %d\n", i, pointerFunc[i]);
```

Both expressions are equivalent and will give you the value stored in the `i`-th element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`pointerFunc` (a bit of a misnomer) is set to the returned value of `func()`, which is `&array[0]` in `func()`. Since `array` is static, it is persistent; the memory allocated for it is still accessible after `func()` returns (vs. an automatic array, which would be UB). Your main loop then prints `array[0]` through `array[9]` using `pointerFunc`. `*(pointerFunc + i)` is equivalent to `pointerFunc[i]`. The former is how `pointerFunc[i]` is actually evaluated, so `i[pointerFunc]` is also equivalent. Not recommended but good for understanding.